# Stop Terminal to auto-put forward slash in front of $HOME

Tags: gnome-terminal, auto-completion

I am running 11.04.

Every time i tried to a command such as

```
mv flieA $HOME/<somedir>/
```

Terminal automatically put "\" in front of $HOME when I hit the 'Tab' key for autocomplete

```
mv flieA \$HOME/<somedir>/
```

it's incredibly annoying, how can i fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `~` instead of `$HOME`. It is shorter to write, and it will not mess up the autocompletion.

```
egil@morgenstern [~] $ ls \$HOME/
egil@morgenstern [~] $ ls ~/
```

Comment: Right that's one solution, however I use a lot of customized env. variables, it does that every time i use "$", is there is a more permanent solution? I don't recall the terminal did that in previous releases.

Comment: The problem lies with Bash. See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00274.html